# svn commit changes made on an older revision

Tags: svn

This ought to be simple, but somehow I can't figure it out:

I updated to the next-to-last revision, let's say revision 100 (HEAD is at 101), like this: `svn up -r 100`. Then I made various changes, and now I want the modified files to be checked in as revision 102 (just so I can get back to 101 if needs be). How do I do that? If I simply do an `svn commit` I get an "out of date" error. I can't do `svn up` either to fix the out-of-date problem because I don't want any of the changes in HEAD (101) to come back...

Comment: Subversion is not designed to work this way.

Comment: OK, but it must be a common use-case... I make changes that don't work 100%, but I do want to commit them for future reference, and go back to an older state from where I take a different path. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your changed files to a temp folder. Rename local repository for backup. Create new local repository. Paste code changes back into files that were copied to temp folder. Commit.

You might want to do a KDiff to confirm all changes are correct before committing.

Hope this helps this problem.

Comment: For some strange reason, `svn merge` did not work, so this suggestion is really useful, thank you. PS: I suppose is safer to remove .svn folders in the new local repo before pasting.

Answer (score 2):

In order to undo the changes of a previous commit, you should use `svn merge`, not `svn up`:

Instead of `svn up -r100`, check out the HEAD revision and do `svn merge -c -101 .`

That results in the same content in your local files, but now subversion will no longer try to reapply revision 101's changes before allowing you to commit.

See also [the svn manual on undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).

Comment: Thanks, I will do it that way in the future. CMcClendon's answer worked for the damage already done though.